# Removing billing dates from WooCommerce Thank you page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove certain details from the WooCommerce thankyou page, when a customer is succesfully purchasing a product. I am unable to find where to look for as am not sure which Hooks or Filter will do the trick.

[image: The field which I don't want to display on thankyou page.]

Any ideas?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the above details are appearing in thank you page after checkout and payment, so I guess i have to use some filter to supress the next bill date field and the details. Adding the above plugin will not serve the purpose I guess

Answer (score 0):

You are using a plugin in order to have recurring orders.

You have to found on the plugin the right filter or action that they are using.

The thank you page template is here : 
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-details.php

I think your plugin is using this hook :

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-details.php#L111

Without your plugin sources, we can't help you

Comment: We have been using WOOCommerce - Subscriptions for the recurring orders.

Comment: Without the source code we can't help you. You have to find in the plugin the use of the hook woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table and show the function called